# Why do Junit tests support only incomplete overriding of fork?

Tags: java, ant, junit, fork

I noticed that Junit batchtest allows overriding junit's forkmode parameter.  Thats good.

However, on further inspection --- it appears that batchtest DOES NOT support the "forkmode" flag ?

This seems quite odd.  It means that the overriden option does not have the same abilities as the junit fork option.

Is this intentional and if so why ?

Comment: Are you speaking about the junit ant task? The question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2):

According to [JUnit Ant task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) you can not override the forkmode parameter in the batchtest.

Typically you would use the forkmode option like this:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" 
       fork="yes" forkmode="perBatch" 
       haltonfailure="${halt.on.test.failure}"
       failureproperty="test.failed">
    <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
    <syspropertyset refid="junit.properties"/>
    <jvmarg value="${test.locale}"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
    <formatter type="plain"/>
    <batchtest todir="${reports.test}">
        <fileset dir="${src.test}">
           <include name="**/Test*.java"/>
           <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

where forkmode could be either "once", "perTest" or "perBatch".

The "perBatch" option is there to create a VM for each nested `<batchtest>`. If you override `<junit>`'s "fork" in `<batchtest>`, you will run your tests in a single VM.

There is no point of having "forkmode" option additionally in `<batchtest>` element(s). You control the VM "forking" modes in the junit element.

Comment: I disagree: it would make sense to have one batch tested with perBatch (same as once for the batch), and another with perTest.

This would allow to run most tests in batches, one JVM per batch, and "problematic" ones one-by-one, and all in the same junit task.

Even better, forkMode="per100" or similar would be great. Clean up via new JVM once in a while, but not for each and every test.